# Unable to retain the default back bar button action after changing it to an image

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGdPk.png) I'm new to iOS. I'm using swift 2 and xcode 7. I'm trying out an app on iphone using splitViewController.I have navigationControllers for both MasterView and DetailView .

The exact problem i'm facing is:
If I'm changing the back bar button item to an image in the DetailView then its default property isn't working.i.e it is not going back to masterview(RootViewController). but I need to have an image for the back button. I have tried a lot of stuff by referring stackOverflow and other few sites.

popToRootViewController and popToViewController cannot be used since I have 2 different navigationController for master and detailview. Now, I want that when I click on backBarButton Image in DetailView, it Should go back to the masterView.

But I'm unable to do it! Please suggest me some way.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put this in your AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` you can change the default back button in all places easily:

```
//Back Image On Whole App
let backImage = UIImage(named: "BackIcon")!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = backImage
```

Change 'BackIcon' to the name of your image in your image assets. Note you have to set the transition mask and rendering mode (as shown above) for it to change the image correctly.

**Update: For just one back button you can use a similar approach by adding this to the screen that pushes (before you see the back button - e.g masterViewController) on viewDidLoad or where you are about to push the detailVC (so you can work out which screen it is about to push to and only change on the one you want):**

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) { 
    if indexPath.row == 1 { 
        //Back Image On The Pushed-to Screen, only on tapped index 1
        let backImage = UIImage(named: "BackIcon")!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = backImage
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = backImage
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil) //To Remove The Title

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetails", sender: self) 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I know this solution but I want to change the image of only one back button and not through out the application.

Comment: I added the above code in the viewDidLoad method of DetailViewController. It didn't work. I'm still getting the default back button.

Comment: You need to add it to the screen that pushes - so in your case the masterViewController - before you see the back button.

Comment: Where do I exactly add this in MasterViewController? which method?

Comment: I added the code to the viewDidLoad method of the masterViewController. The image appears but also the text (Back) is visible and is appearing on the viewControllers linked to the masterViewController as well!

Comment: Okay, how do you push to the detailVC, didSelectAtIndexPath or segue? You will need to add the code when your are about to push the view controller and will need to check which detailVC it is going to, so you only change it on the one you need. For removing the title, check my updated code again

Comment: Did you refer my screenshot? The detailView is the one which appears first when app is launched. Again from masterViewController i have a navigationController which is further linked to other viewControllers. masterViewController and navigationViewController are linked by segue. I'm writing the following code in my masterViewController:                     override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showDetails", sender: self)
        }
    }

Comment: Yeah so in your didSelectRowAtIndex in the part that checks what indexPath was clicked add the code in my answer, before you performSegueWithIdentifier. That way it will only change the back button if index path is 1 for example, for the one you want.

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked :) BTW just one more question, I still get default back button for the first time when detailView appears. Next time when I click a Button to go back to my detailView the image appears as I have written your code in prepareForSegue method.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, can you explain further?

Comment: When I open the app, the detailViewController will be shown up and it displays the back default button. Like you know this detailView is the first view to appear when app launches. Then when i go to masterView and again go to detailView then image for button will appear.

Comment: How does the detailVC have a back button if it's the first screen? I don't quite get your set up

Comment: In splitviewController, iPhone portrait mode, detailview will appear first. This is how it works.. isn't it?

Comment: Doesn't the menu/masterVC tableview show first and then you tap into an option/detailVC...like in settings. Settings tableview is shown first and then you can into each section etc.

Comment: My app shows me the detailViewController first and upon tapping the back button masterView appears! I'm not sure which is right though. And i haven't changed anything in the code. So this is the default thing which i'm seeing.

Comment: I don't know then why am i getting the detailView popped up as the first screen!